# How to add inner fields to a json in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json similar to this :

```
{"Details": {
  "id": "1423",
  "StudentName": "xxx",
  "Joineddate" : "yyy",
  "Personalinfo" : "na"

}}
```

Now I have to update my json to the following :

```
{"Details": {
  "id": 1423,
  "StudentName": "xxx",
  "Joineddate" : "yyy",
  "Personalinfo" : 
  {
    "age" : "30",
    "Address" : "xxxxx"
  }

}}
```

I don't know how to achieve this in python. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON into a Python structure yet? Where are you stuck on manipulating the Python dictionaries that you then have?

Comment: I am struck in adding inner filelds. I am able to add a field in python

Comment: But inner objects are just more dictionaries. If you parsed the JSON into a Python structure bound as `data`, then `data['Details']` is another dictionary, just like `data` itself is a dictionary. There is nothing special about that nested dictionary.

Comment: `nested = data['Details']`, `nested['Personalinfo'] = {'age': '30', 'Address': 'xxxxx'}` for example. Or directly use `data['Details']['Personalinfo'] = {'age': '30', 'Address': 'xxxxx'}`

Comment: Thanks @Martijn
I got it

Answer (score 0):

You can use demjson :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_python_example.htm

```
data= demjson.decode(json)
print  data
```

Then add your data, then :

```
json = demjson.encode(data)
print json
```